# Copying a file from a linux embedded system to local machine connected by a Serial connection

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, csv, scp

I am connected to my embedded system by serial connection to my laptop(windows), and using puTTy I booted it up. It is collecting data and making a .csv file of the collected data. I would like to get that .csv from the system and save it to my laptop but I do not know how to do that. I searched and found scp command but it sends data from remote server to machine or machine to remote server, but I dont have a server. I am also new to linux commands. Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: I was able to copy after making a DHCP server on my laptop and then connected the device with an ethernet cable and used scp.